# "We're all each other has"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I heard this phrase

> We're all each other has.

in Family Guy and [a quick googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we%27re%20all%20each%20other%20has%22) shows about a hundred thousand occurrences. It sounds really strange to me. I would say

> We are all we have.

Now that I think of it, *"We are all we have"* technically means *"We have us"* rather than *"We have each other"*, although I suppose context could render the two meanings equivalent.

In *"We're all each other has"*, however, it is emphasized that *"We have each other"*. Here *each other* is used as the subject rather than the object (of the subordinate clause), which seems illogical. Is this usage acceptable in standard English? If not, is it uncommon? I mean, does it hit the ear wrong for native speakers? Should I avoid using it even in informal speech?

Comment: It sounds fine to me. "Each" takes the singular, even when it is in the phrase "each other".

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, it does, but my question isn't about the numeric agreement, it is about using *each other* as a subject.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. As the subject of a subordinate clause, it still sounds fine to me. It usually wouldn't as the subject of a main clause, though.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks, Peter. Does "sounds fine to me" imply that "it is acceptable in Standard English"? Would you use this kind of structure in a business letter, for example?

Comment: It's certainly acceptable in standard English, whatever that may be, but whether it's acceptable in a business letter is another question. I often say it to my son about his new family (his mother died & I remarried, but he still doesn't consider himself part of my wife's very large family even though I do -- they're all Taiwanese & I'm the only foreigner (my son's Taiwanese too) at family gatherings). It's not something that'd often be used in business letters, though. It's kind of sentimental, I think, & the sort of thing that close friends & relatives would say during hard times.

Comment: Family Guy scripts often "play" with language, but I think with the kind of budget they have, it's unlikely anything "accidental" would slip through unnoticed. In this case I agree *"We're all each other has"* does sound slightly "strange", but I can't see there's any grammatical principle which would disallow it whilst accepting *"We have each other"*.

Comment: I read it as "we are all [that] each other has" - i.e., "each other is all that we have", "we have nothing but each other."

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I read it exactly as you do and "Each other is all that we have" and "we have nothing but each other" both sound perfectly fine to me, unlike "we are all that each other has"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This fascinating sentence is impossible to parse strictly, because the phrase *each other* has become, in our linguistic consciousness, divorced from the original structure which generated it.

1) That underlying structure is something like:

> ***Each of us has the other***(s). (the plural being employed when there are more than two of us)

2) This becomes

> ***We have, each the other***(s).

3) This is generalized as

> ***We have each other.***

4) So far, so good. What happens next is that ***each other*** becomes apprehended as a fixed noun phrase, still *signifying* the reciprocal relationship but *no longer constrained* to a strict syntactical coherence. (I make no claim that what follows represents an actual historical development — just a sort of underlying logic.)

> ***What we have is each other.***  or ***All we have is each other.***
>   ***Each other is all we have.***   or ***Each other is all we have.***

5) This now runs up against a *semantically equivalent* construction:

> **We** ***are all we have.***

6) But since in 4) *all we have* is *each other*, the penultimate stage is to substitute *each other* for *we* as a sort of reciprocal pronoun

> ***We're all each other have.***

7) And the final stage is to replace *have*, reflecting what our high-school teachers drummed into us — that *each* takes *has*.

> ***We're all each other has.***

Comment: Good analyses. The teachers you mention probably haven't contributed to the 321 000 hits on Google at my space-time coordinates for "we each have".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Some of us fail high school, others of us transcend it.

Answer (score 0):

We are all we have.
All we have is each other.
We have nothing save each other.

"We're all each other has" is just a lazy way of saying something incorrectly and still getting your meaning across. Happening more and more as people not only care less and less, but even NOTICE less and less when there is incorrect grammar, etc. in mass media. Oh well! :)

Answer (score 0):

For example: suppose

> I am all she has, and she is all I have.

To summarize, I might say

> We are all each other has.

Answer (score -1):

"We" is plural, hence "We are..."   All is singular, isn't it?  Hence, "all has." We are all, and then all has.

Comment: This is wrong. *All* is not the subject of the verb *has*; it is the object. That's like saying "We has a car" is correct, because *car* is third-person singular.