# Should it be: "each other's belongings" or "each others' belongings"?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, apostrophe

In this sentence:

> I'm proud we're not one of those couples who have to snoop through
>   each other's belongings.

Is the above correct? Or should it be "each others' belongings"? Can you ever say *each others'* in any situation?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Thanks that helped, though I see there are different schools of thought!

Comment: I believe this question should remain open. I have voted to close the previous question (the one that has been put forward as being a duplicate) because it is ill-defined and based on a false premise. The question here is clear and well-defined/

Comment: Related though probably not duplicate:[We're all each other has](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91887/8019).

Comment: Thanks Tim. On a related note, is it ok to say, "our eyes bore into each other?"

Comment: @Monique - That would be a strange statement because it would imply the people involved were cross-eyed (or maybe the use of mirrors).  Under normal circumstances you should say,  "Our eyes bore into each other's [eyes].   If you mean that each person's eyes bore into the other *person* (rather than the other person's eyes) then you have to spell it out -- you can't use 'each other'.

Comment: Yes, I mean "my eyes bore into his eyes." Does it just sound weird to say " our eyes bore into each other?"

Comment: Though chasly is correct, note that the past tense is *bored*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple way to understand this. Forget about the possessive aspect and ask yourself the question:

Can 'each other' ***ever*** be plural? The answer is no. Here's an example:

Imagine a football team. Every member gives a Christmas card to every other member. There are many people and many cards. Does that mean 'other' should be plural? Let's try:

> The members of the team all gave each *others* a Christmas card.

Any native speaker, whether they have a knowledge of grammar or not, will say that that is wrong. They will tell you to say:

> The members of the team all gave each *other* a Christmas card.

The reason is that 'each' is always singular and can only modify a singular noun.

Another way to see the same thing is to consider 'each other' as meaning 'each other person'. You would say *each other person's belongings* but never *each other persons' belongings.*

**Answer**

It is always *each other* and there is no context in which it could be *each others*.  This holds true even if you add the apostrophe to make the expression possessive.

The correct usage would would be:

> The members of the team like their cards and admired each other's presents.

**Update in response to a comment**

The following passage supports my argument that 'each other' is correct and 'each others' is incorrect.

> Every, like each, is always used with a singular noun form and
>   therefore with a singular verb form in English because we are counting
>   the things or people that we are talking about separately one by one:
>
> Every child in the class plays a musical instrument. Every instrument
>   belonging to the school is tuned regularly. everybody / everyone /
>   everything
>
> [Learning English - BBC World Service](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv266.shtml)

Comment: Do you disagree with me that the question is a duplicate of the following one: [Should “each” be followed by a singular or plural possessive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92007/should-each-be-followed-by-a-singular-or-plural-possessive)? If not (that is, if you do agree with me), why did you post an answer here rather than voting to close and posting an answer at the linked question?

Comment: I think that what makes this question different is the final question:  'Can you ever say *each others'* in any situation?'*  I focused on answering that.  You can never correctly say it in any context.

Comment: How does that make it any different? Your answer would fit in fine on the other page; one of the answers there starts with "Surely it's **always** *each others*" (bolding added by me). It's inconvenient that you posted your answer here because it makes it harder to compare to the answers on the other page, and anyone who finds the other page will have to click on the links to see your answer.

Comment: I'll have another look.

Comment: But what about the answers to the previous question? Honestly, I don't think your answer adds that much compared to them. You simply assert: "Can 'each other' ever be plural? The answer is no." However, you never demonstrate that it can *never* be plural. You demonstrate that it is not plural in one particular example sentence that you give. And you are not an authority on English grammar anyway, as far as I know, so you should really provide an external reference to back up your claims. The top-voted answer on the other question seems to say the same thing as you.

Comment: Okay. I've looked again. I'm voting to close that other question as it is based on a false premise in its first sentence. This makes the rest of the question suspect and therefore leads to off-topic arguments about the specific example. This question is better defined and therefore, in my opinion, should stand.

Comment: However, if you really feel the other question is so terrible and should be closed as a duplicate of this one, I think you ought to contact a moderator (possibly through a meta post) to get the previous answers migrated to this one. Anyway, here's a relevant meta post about marking older questions as duplicates of newer ones: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/is-it-appropriate-to-mark-an-earlier-poorer-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-later?lq=1

Comment: Okay. You have pointed out a perceived  inadequacy in my *answer*.   I'll look into that. However the correctness or otherwise of my answer has no bearing on the validity of the *question*.  I still say that this question is well-defined.  I have made my argument that the other is not valid in a comment on the other question. That is where you should debate my reasoning about that question - not here.

Comment: I don't think the other answers should be migrated here. That question and its answers were a complete mess. I don't think we should inflict someone else's problems on this OP.  I've looked at the meta question and answers you refer to. I see them as supporting my position.

Comment: Thank you so much Chasly - that is really useful. Just to confirm, when you add something like *belongings*, you would need to add the apostrophe before the S--is that right. i.e. each other's belongings? Thanks so much for your advice.

Comment: It's true that the previous question I was referred to was similar to mine, though I didn't choose to close my question just yet as I got no definite answer from the comments left in response to the other question, so wanted to see if anyone had another opinion. I don't mind closing it. I found that Chasly helped me a lot. It is singular always, so should be *each other's belongings.*

Comment: @MoniqueH - Yes, I can confirm --->  *each other's belongings*.  NOTE: I prefer that you keep this question open. It will be of more use to future readers than the other one.